# Why angular 4 componet's view doesn't rerender when component's properties are changed in subscription callbacks?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subscription

I have written authentiction system in angular 4 using RxJS Observer feature. Querying to Oracle database is based on querystream converted to observer/observable in service, then in login component with log in form I subscribe to obervable in service to get result of authentication. Service's observable object, which is returned by method, publishes "true" or "false" if user is authenticated or not. By clicking on login button in login form component the loading animation is shown and login form is hidden. When user is authenticated router redirects user to feature pages. When user is not authenticated the loading animation is hidden and login form is shown again. But this does not work as expected. In console i see output that user is not logged in, and at the same time loading animation is still shown, form is hidden, despite properties of component display showLoading = false and showLoginForm = true

**login.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DbSelectService } from '../db/db-select.service';
import * as md5 from 'js-md5';
import { AuthModel, CurrentUserModel } from '../../data-models/data-models.interfaces';
import { DbSelectQueryParams } from '../../data-models/data-models.interfaces';
import { CurrentUserDbRow } from '../../data-models/db-responses.interfaces';
import { SessionService } from '../core/session.service';
import { CacheService } from '../feature/cache.service';
import { LoggerService } from '../core/logger.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    private currentAuthData: AuthModel;
    private currentUser: CurrentUserModel;

    constructor (
        private dbSelect: DbSelectService,
        private sessionService: SessionService,
        private cacheService: CacheService,
        private logger: LoggerService
    ) {

        this.currentAuthData = this.cacheService.getCurrentAuthDataCache();
        this.currentUser = this.cacheService.getCurrentUser();

    }

    checkAccessRights (): Observable<boolean> {

        return new Observable( (observer: Observer<boolean>) => {

            const queryParams: DbSelectQueryParams = {
                fields: [
                    `NAME`,
                    `ROLE`
                ],
                tables: [
                    `SINS.P_USER`
                ],
                conditions: [
                    `UPPER(P_USER.NAME) = UPPER(:username)`,
                    `AND`,
                    `PSWD = :password`,
                    `AND`,
                    `HASH = :hash`,
                    `AND`,
                    `LOCKED <> '1'`,
                    `AND`,
                    `ROWNUM = 1`
                ]
            };

            const bindParams = {
                username: this.currentAuthData.username,
                password: this.currentAuthData.password,
                hash: md5(this.currentAuthData.password)
            };

            let userIsAuthenticated = false;
            const AUTHENTICATED = true;
            const NOT_AUTHENTICATED = false;

            this.dbSelect.select<CurrentUserDbRow>(queryParams, bindParams).subscribe(
                user => {

                    console.warn(user);
                    this.currentUser.username = user.NAME.toUpperCase();
                    this.currentUser.role = user.ROLE.toLowerCase();

                    this.sessionService.getAccessToUser();

                    userIsAuthenticated = true;

                    observer.next(AUTHENTICATED);
                    observer.complete();

                },
                err => {

                    observer.error(err);
                    this.logger.writeError(err);
                    this.sessionService.closeSession();

                },
                () => {

                    observer.next(NOT_AUTHENTICATED);
                    observer.complete();

                    if (userIsAuthenticated === NOT_AUTHENTICATED) {
                        this.logger.writeNewError('logon denied');
                        this.sessionService.closeSession();
                    }

                }
            );

        } );

    }


}
```

**login.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppConfig } from '../services/core/app-config.service';
import { remote } from 'electron';
import { LoginService } from '../services/auth/login.service';
import { AuthModel } from '../data-models/data-models.interfaces';
import { ToastService } from '../services/core/toast.service';
import { CacheService } from '../services/feature/cache.service';
import { AppConfigParamsModel, MaxLengthAndValueModel } from '../data-models/data-models.interfaces';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    styleUrls: ['app/login/login.component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'app/login/login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private pagename = 'Логин';
    private showLoading = false;
    private showLoginForm = true;
    private loginSubscription: Subscription;

    private authmodel: AuthModel;

    private maxlength: MaxLengthAndValueModel = {
        username: 32,
        password: 32
    };

    constructor (
        private titleService: Title,
        private config: AppConfig,
        private loginService: LoginService,
        private toastService: ToastService,
        private cacheService: CacheService
    ) {

        this.authmodel = this.cacheService.getCurrentAuthDataCache();

    }

    ngOnInit () {

        this.config.getParams().then( (params: AppConfigParamsModel) => {

            this.titleService.setTitle( `${params.appname} - ${this.pagename}` );

        } );

    }


    ngOnDestroy () {

        if (this.loginSubscription) {
            this.loginSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }

    }


    private onLogin (): void {

        this.showLoadingAnimation();

        this.loginSubscription = this.loginService.checkAccessRights().subscribe(
            accessAllowed => {

                if (accessAllowed) {

                    this.toastService.showAdviceToast('Добро пожаловать!');

                } else {

                    this.hideLoadingAnimation();
                    this.toastService.showErrorToastWithAdvice('ВХОД ЗАПРЕЩЁН', 'Обратитесь к администратору');

                }

            },
            err => {

                this.hideLoadingAnimation();
                this.toastService.showErrorToastWithAdvice('Не удалось войти', 'Попробуйте ещё раз');

            }
        );

    }


    private closeWindow (): void {

        remote.getCurrentWindow().close();

    }


    private showLoadingAnimation(): void {

        this.showLoading = true;
        this.showLoginForm = false;
        console.warn(this);

    }


    private hideLoadingAnimation(): void {

        this.showLoading = false;
        this.showLoginForm = true;
        console.warn(this);

    }


}
```

But if i change service method just for experiment just like shown bellow (without subscription to querying results) component's view is rerendered well.

```js
checkAccessRights (): Observable<boolean> {

        return new Observable( (observer: Observer<boolean>) => {

            const AUTHENTICATED = true;
            const NOT_AUTHENTICATED = false;

            this.currentUser.username = 'ADMIN';
            this.currentUser.role = 'admin';
            this.sessionService.getAccessToUser();
            observer.next(AUTHENTICATED);
            observer.complete();

        } );

    }
```

I want to note, that everything works if i use Promise instead of Observer.

**in service**

```js
checkAccessRights (): Promise<boolean> {

        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

            const queryParams: DbSelectQueryParams = {
                fields: [
                    `NAME`,
                    `ROLE`
                ],
                tables: [
                    `SINS.P_USER`
                ],
                conditions: [
                    `UPPER(P_USER.NAME) = UPPER(:username)`,
                    `AND`,
                    `PSWD = :password`,
                    `AND`,
                    `HASH = :hash`,
                    `AND`,
                    `LOCKED <> '1'`,
                    `AND`,
                    `ROWNUM = 1`
                ]
            };

            const bindParams = {
                username: this.currentAuthData.username,
                password: this.currentAuthData.password,
                hash: md5(this.currentAuthData.password)
            };

            let userIsAuthenticated = false;
            const AUTHENTICATED = true;
            const NOT_AUTHENTICATED = false;

            this.dbSelect.select<CurrentUserDbRow>(queryParams, bindParams).subscribe(
                user => {

                    console.warn(user);
                    this.currentUser.username = user.NAME.toUpperCase();
                    this.currentUser.role = user.ROLE.toLowerCase();

                    this.sessionService.getAccessToUser();

                    userIsAuthenticated = true;

                    resolve(AUTHENTICATED);

                },
                err => {

                    reject(err);
                    this.logger.writeError(err);

                },
                () => {

                    resolve(NOT_AUTHENTICATED);

                    if (userIsAuthenticated === NOT_AUTHENTICATED) {
                        this.logger.writeNewError('logon denied');
                    }

                }
            );

        } );

    }
```

**in component**

```js
this.loginService.checkAccessRights().then(
            accessAllowed => {

                if (accessAllowed) {

                    this.toastService.showAdviceToast('Добро пожаловать!');

                } else {

                    this.hideLoadingAnimation();
                    this.toastService.showErrorToastWithAdvice('ВХОД ЗАПРЕЩЁН', 'Обратитесь к администратору');

                }

            }
        ).catch(
            err => {

                this.hideLoadingAnimation();
                this.toastService.showErrorToastWithAdvice('Не удалось войти', 'Попробуйте ещё раз');

            }
        );
```

Help me, please, to solve this issue and make component rerendering as expected.

Comment: Sometimes, the problem comes from the unsubscribe method.

Comment: In previous version of this code the unsubscribe method was absent, and problem was the same

Answer (score 0):

Try to change a few things:

- Annotate your component fields as correct inputs -- just prepend them with `@Input`;
- Make those fields public, either by specifying it explicitly or simply by removing the keyword `private`.

---

```
  @Input() showLoading = false;
  @Input() showLoginForm = true;
```

Comment: This also did not solve the problem. I want to note that everything works if i use Promise instead of Observer.